# getting the visible item in an horizontal listview android

Tags: android, listview

I have a horizontal scrollable list view. I need to find the index of the first visible position in it...in the cas eof vertical listviews there is a method onScroll(`AbsListView` view, int `firstVisibleItem`, int `visibleItemCount`, int `totalItemCount`) to do this...can someone guide me for a horizontal list view

Comment: I guess it depends on the implementation of you horizontal listview. There are multiple different implementations of a horizontal listview to be found online. details of which one are necessary to anwer this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();` method for this. This will return the index (= position) of that item. With that index you can find your item by using `ListView.get(index);`